# How to fix list index out of range error when loading in a Magnitude file using pymagnitude?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am currently writing code which will use the most similar words by word embedding using ELMo (Embedding Language Model). The tutorial on their website states that the .magnitude file can simply be downloaded, with the vocabulary and loaded using their inbuilt Magnitude(filepath) function. I do not know why this is failing, any help would be appreciated.

I have tried downloading multiple magnitude files from their website including word2vec, ELMo without vocabulary, and ELMo with vocabulary.

```
vecs = Magnitude('/home/user/Desktop/CAR/complex-answer-retrieval/Embeddings/ELMO/elmo_without_vocab.magnitude')
vecs = Magnitude('/home/user/Desktop/CAR/complex-answer-retrieval/Embeddings/ELMO/elmo_with_vocab.magnitude')
```

I expect the former to load the file and the most_similar function to fail as this elmo model is not linked to any vocabulary.

The second line does not load correctly giving this error:

```
self.length = self._db().execute("SELECT value FROM magnitude_format WHERE key='size'").fetchall()[0][0]
version_query = self._db().execute("SELECT value FROM magnitude_format WHERE key='version'")

IndexError: list index out of range
```